# Class Variables in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am having difficulties testing this in rspec:

```
class RootOrganization
  include ClassLevelInheritableAttributes
  inheritable_attributes :role

  @role = "Admin"
end

class Organization < RootOrganization
end

end

class ChildOrganizationOne < Organization
end

p ChildOrganizationOne.role #=> "Admin"
ChildOrganizationOne.role = "User"
p ChildOrganizationOne.role #=> "User"
```

Does anyone know how I can set these variables in rspec? I want to show that if
RootOrganization.role = "Admin" and Organization.role = "User" that ChildOrganizationOne.role should equal "User"?

(below is the module created for reference)

```
module ClassLevelInheritableAttributes
def self.included(base)
 base.extend(ClassMethods)    
end

module ClassMethods
def inheritable_attributes(*args)
  @inheritable_attributes ||= [:inheritable_attributes]
  @inheritable_attributes += args
  args.each do |arg|
    class_eval %(
      class << self; attr_accessor :#{arg} end
    )
  end
  @inheritable_attributes
end

def inherited(subclass)
  @inheritable_attributes.each do |inheritable_attribute|
    instance_var = "@#{inheritable_attribute}"
    subclass.instance_variable_set(instance_var, instance_variable_get(instance_var))
  end
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [stub](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/method-stubs) the `role` attributes to return the need values:

```
it "returns child organization as user" do
  allow(RootOrganization).to receive(:role).and_return("Admin")
  allow(Organization).to receive(:role).and_return("User")

  expect(ChildOrganizationOne.role).to eq "User"
end
```